# Visual Studio setting for quoted text in script tags?

Tags: visual-studio

Not a direct programming question but related.  I have been setting my fonts and colors in Visual Studio 2010.  My quoted strings are showing as Maroon against a black background and I can't seem to find a setting to change the color.  I tried to reset all my settings and the default with the white background still shows this color as maroon.

Anyone know how I can change it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors -> Display Items ["String"] = <Your color>
```

Comment: Try other parameters in that list in the XAML and XML groups.

Comment: Found it finally....there has to be a better way to set the font colors ;)
It wsa "Script String" which is blatently obvious now